# Full width Headers and Images CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand how to get a full width header. The problem is it has a thin white border around the header and is not full width. I am not using any grid system if that matters.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

     <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" display="screen" > 

 <title>
    test app
 </title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="header"/>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#header {

    float:left;
    padding:15px 0;
    min-width:100%;
    background: #5FBEED;

}
```

Any help much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem to be getting the white border around it. A `div` automatically fills the entire window's width, so remove that `min-width` style: **[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nWfD/)**.

CSS:

```
#header {
    padding: 15px 0;
    border: 10px solid white;
    background: #5FBEED;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i don't want the thin white border, that's my point. Mine looks like your fiddle without the border styling. So it has that thin white border without my declaring one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
body{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Browsers add their own css to html elements and this varies from browser to browser. The margin and padding is also applied to UL and few other elements...

You can read more about this here... http://clagnut.com/blog/1287/

Comment: The technique mentioned in the linked article is dangerous imho. `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` breaks user contributed HTML… I work with a lot of ecommerce stores, and sometimes we farm our slicing out to a third party. When they add that dangerous little snippet, the store owner's product details UL-LIs break, paragraphs cease to be spaced properly, and many other issues appear. I personally prefer targeted resets with shared CSS using [SASS's `@extend`](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend), or a [normalization CSS file](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/).

Comment: Worked Perfectly thanks! I will vote up when i have enough reputation and in regards thirdender. I am currently just a beginner but i will look into CSS resets and SASS when i get to a higher level thank you also for your response.

Comment: I agree with thirdender, until you know what you are doing do not use *{ margin: 0; }

Answer (score 0):

The white border is mostly likely added by the `BODY` tag's inherent `margin`. Try adding the following CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Also worked a treat. Will also vote up when i have enough reputation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body{
padding: 0;
margin 0;
```

}

```
#header {
padding: 15px 0;
border: 10px solid #5FBEED;
background: #5FBEED;
```

}

in this case your borders will be the same color as your header background color